# Detect trackpad touch events from NSResponder when cursor is over Dock bar in macOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, touch

I created a Cocoa app for macOS and implemented the `touchesBeganWithEvent`, `touchesMovedWithEvent`, `touchesEndedWithEvent` and `touchesCancelledWithEvent` methods from the `NSResponder` interface in Objective-C.

The touches in the trackpad are detected when they begin over the app's window, as intended, even when I drag the cursor outside the window's edges.

The only time the touches aren't detected is when I drag the cursor over the Dock bar (for example, I can't detect if a touch ended when I lift my finger from the trackpad and the cursor is over the Dock bar).

Is there any way for my app to detect that the cursor is over the Dock bar?